# How to use tone in two pins?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a buzzer and an IR led emitter so I have to use the tone function to sound the buzzer and to modulate the output of the LED.
I have connected the led pin 5 of the arduino, the buzzer pin A0.

```
int tones[] = {261, 277, 294, 280, 230};
const int pinBuzzer = A0;
const int cr_pin = 5;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(1200);
  tone(cr_pin, 38000);  /* For modulation at 38kHz */
  pinMode(pinBuzzer, OUTPUT);
}

void soundBuzzer() {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof tones; i ++) { 
    tone(pinBuzzer, tones[i]);
  } 
    noTone(pinBuzzer);  
}


void irLED() {
  Serial.println("Hello");
}
```

This is my code but I can not make the led and the buzzer work at the same time, apparently the buzzer is affected by the tone line `(cr_pin, 38000); / * For modulation at 38kHz * /.`

I tried to remove `(cr_pin, 38000); / * For modulation at 38kHz * /.` of the setup and leave code in the following way.

```
int tones[] = {261, 277, 294, 280, 230};
const int pinBuzzer = A0;
const int cr_pin = 5;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(1200);
  pinMode(pinBuzzer, OUTPUT);
}

void soundBuzzer() {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof tones; i ++) { 
    tone(pinBuzzer, tones[i]);
  } 
    noTone(pinBuzzer);  
}


void irLED() {
tone(cr_pin, 38000);  /* For modulation at 38kHz */
      Serial.println("Hello");
noTone(cr_pin);
    }
```

In the first code the LED works but not the buzzer and in the second code the buzzer now works but not the LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one tone can be generated at a time. If a tone is already playing on a different pin, the call to `tone()` will have no effect. If the tone is playing on the same pin, the call will set its frequency. Source: [arduino.cc - tone()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/).

`noTone()` Stops the generation of a square wave triggered by `tone()`. Has no effect if no tone is being generated. Source: [arduino.cc - noTone()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/notone/)